# How to write MDX formula for a filter

Tags: ssrs-2008, formula, mdx

I am working on a report in BI that includes 2 datasets. The screenshot below is of DataSet2 where I am trying to write a MDX filter expression for the query. What is the formula so that the query only shows rows from the past 2 months from today. I tried a few different formulas…[GamingDay].[Date] > CDate(DateAdd(‘m’,-2,Now())) and it returns an error. What is the correct formula to do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MjlQ.png)

Comment: Are you able to write MDX with a hardcoded date such as `1 January 2019` first? Do that before trying the `CDate()` expression, and let us know what your full MDX query was.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes to resolve the issue. Take a look at the sample below

```
with member measures.t 
as 
CDate(
DateAdd("m",-2,Now())
)
select 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.t }
on columns,
[Product].[Category].[Category]
on rows
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result[image]

Comment: @devlinch does the above help